# Can an NSPanel have NSViews that are swapped in and out?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I can find plenty of documentation on swapping out views in a window, but not in a panel is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSPanel` is a subclass of `NSWindow`, so anything you read about swapping views in windows should work identically on panels.

Comment: A reminder: When looking for something in a class reference, always look at the superclasses!

Comment: This functionality is part of `NSView`, the `NSWindow` superclass.